# std::optional does not compile

Tags: c++, std, stdoptional

This code does not compile with the command  g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/optional>

int main()
{
    std::optional<int> x;
    std::cout << "Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

The Errors are the following:

1. error: ‘optional’ is not a member of ‘std’
2. error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’

Is there a way to get this code to compile?

Answer (score 9):

The `<experimental/optional>` header doesn't define `std::optional` but rather `std::experimental::optional`.  To get `std::optional`, which is a (non-experimental) part of the C++17 standard, you should just `#include <optional>`.

[Try on godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/E6EfxW)